# Javascript regexp using val().match() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a field named phone_number with this rules:

the first digit should be 3 then another 9 digits so in total 10 number example: 3216549874

or can be 7 numbers 1234567

here i have my code:

```
        if (!($("#" + val["htmlId"]).val().match(/^3\d{9}|\d{7}/)))
            missing = true;
```

Why doesnt work :( when i put that into an online regexp checker shows good.

Comment: A few too many "val" ? val[] and val()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using test instead of match and here's the proper code:

```
.test(/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})$/)
```

Match will find all the occurrences, while test will only check to see if at least one is available (thus validating your number).

Comment: if (!($("#" + val["htmlId"]).val().test(/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})$/))) doesnt work

Comment: then you have a problem with your jQuery code, test in the Firebug console like this: '3216549874'.test(/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})$/)

Comment: i got another sentence like

 else if (tipPersoana == 1 && key == 2) {
   if (!($("#" + val["htmlId"]).val().match(/[a-zA-Z]|\d{1,12}/)))
    missing = true;
  }

Comment: @alessioalex `/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})$/.test('3216549874')` as in `regexObj.test(str)`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't get confused by pipe. Must end each expression

```
if (!($("#" + val["htmlId"]).val().match(/^3\d{9}/|/\d{7}/)))
            missing = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alfabravoteam/e6jKs/

Comment: yeah i have another rule like /.+/ and works this too if (!($("#" + val["htmlId"]).val().match(/[a-zA-Z]|\d{1,12}/)))

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and my solution was to write it like:

```
if (/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})$/.test($("#" + val["htmlId"]).val()) == false) {
    missing = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a little more strict.

```
.match(/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})$/)
```